# Frequent ping-ponging of priorities?

Tags: grammar

I came through the following sentence in a technical research paper. Is it correct to use `ping-ponging` word? Please let me know.

> With TS policy, priorities of threads change very frequently for
>   balancing load and providing fairness in scheduling. Due to this
>   frequent ping-ponging of priorities, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Ping-pong" doesn't just refer to table-tennis. [It refers to when something is being switched back and forth between two entities](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ping-pong). Thus, "ping-ponging of priorities" would be quite correct.

Basically means:

> Due to this frequent switching back and forth of priorities.

"Ping-ponging" is correctly used here.